# Show message box when a specifc program ".exe" open

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I`m playing a game which take around 30 sec to load and open , so I decided to create a please wait app for it
the app idea is : 
User click on it then my app will open the game and say please wait label will appear then **my app will close its self**.

The problem is I don't know how to make my app show message saying "Welcome to XXX " then close when **"DMC.exe" open**

Thanks ^^

Comment: What You are looking for isn't a message box but a splash screen (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.splashscreen(v=vs.100).aspx )

Comment: something like a splash screen but for a different exe not for my own app 
ty ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how "DMC.exe" is written, but the simplest solution would be to try with [Process.WaitForInputIdle()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d7363e2(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Causes the Process component to wait indefinitely for the associated
>   process to enter an idle state.

An "idle state" is often reached once the main window has been displayed and is waiting for user input:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private P As Process
    Private T As System.Threading.Thread

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Shown
        P = Process.Start("dmc.exe")
        T = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf Wait)
        T.Start()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Wait()
        P.WaitForInputIdle()
        Application.Exit()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Using threading and your code seems like the best solution 
but I want ask is idle state mean when game open in background or when game start responding .... Because games usually start in background then keep taking ram until it load everything 
so I have feelings that the code is going to  close the app when the game  open and appear in task manager not when it start responding

Thanks a lot ^^

Comment: Sorry I know I didn't say in the post I wanna app close when game start responding but I though you guys will know that /

Comment: As I said, this is dependent upon **HOW** the application was written (something you can't know); you'll just have to try it out and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

According to the .exe time load around 30 sec then

1. make a form called "loadingform" (or any).
2. add your timer to "loadingform"
3. Put this code at your timer

> ```
>         Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
>         Me.Hide() '   "Me" your loadingform 
>           Timer1.Dispose()
>           'Do anything after your loadingform hide
>         End Sub
> ```

4. Change "timer1" properties to:

   - Enabled = True
   - Interval = 30000

Comment: by the way DMC is that Devil May Cry ? oh I love that game lol :D. But according to PC specification, if the game loading well (faster loading) or not so well (slower loading) you need to do like Idle_Mind said below.

Comment: timer interval is very simple way and 30 second was an example and game doesn't talk 30 sec every time and DMC yea I played this game many times but in my post DMC is just an example not what I'm really working on :P
Thanks bud :)